# How to show keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard

I do not understand how to show keyboard for my custom widget.

I want to build a custom widget that could receive keyboard events and draw text on canvas.

I have tried approach described in [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Focus-class.html) with no result (though I have able to receive key events from my pc keyboard on emulator without showing soft keyboard. It is also not showing keyboard on real device)

Here is my code which I thought should pop-up keyboard on tap:

```
class CrossGridWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _CrossGridState();
  }
}

class _CrossGridState extends State<CrossGridWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return FocusScope(
            debugLabel: 'Scope',
            autofocus: true,
            child: Focus(
                debugLabel: 'Focus',
                onKey: (node, event) {
                  if (event.logicalKey.keyLabel.isNotEmpty) {
                    print(event.logicalKey);
                    return KeyEventResult.handled;
                  }
                  return KeyEventResult.ignored;
                },
                child: _buildGrid()
            ),
          );
  }

  Widget _buildGrid() {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) => GestureDetector(onTapDown: (details) {
        final focusNode = Focus.of(context);
        print(focusNode.hasFocus);
        if (!focusNode.hasFocus) {
          focusNode.requestFocus();
        }
      }, child: Consumer<Game>(
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Text('test'));
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `onTap` instead of `onTapDown` please?

Comment: not sure if it is right approach, but adding this line shows up keyboard on android, but not ios

    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? I have the exact same question (and a very similar use case), but I haven't been able to find anything that works.

Comment: @user1902853 I ended up adding to view tree hidden textField